# Analog clock in React.js, rendered using CSS rotation

Tags: datetime, animation, dom, react.js, jsx

I am new to ReactJS and I am trying to write a component which emulates an analog clock. The second, minutes and hour div elements are transformed every second using an interval function. However, I am wondering if there is a better way of transforming the styles for them in the `setDate()` function?

It seems that what I have written directly modifies the DOM rather than using the Virtual DOM that React provides.

```
import React from 'react';

class Clock extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            timer: setInterval(this.setDate, 1000)
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.state.timer);
    }

    setDate() {
        const secondHand = document.querySelector('.second-hand');
        const minutesHand = document.querySelector('.min-hand');
        const hourHand = document.querySelector('.hour-hand');

        const now = new Date();
        const second = now.getSeconds();
        const minute = now.getMinutes();
        const hour = now.getHours();

        const secondDegrees = (second/60) * 360 + 90;
        const minutesDegrees = (minute/60) * 360 + 90;
        const hourDegrees = (hour/12) * 360 + 90;

        secondHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondDegrees}deg)`;
        minutesHand.style.transform = `rotate(${minutesDegrees}deg)`;
        hourHand.style.transform = `rotate(${hourDegrees}deg)`;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="col-md-6">
                <div className="clock">
                    <div className="clock-face">
                        <div className="hand hour-hand"></div>
                        <div className="hand min-hand"></div>
                        <div className="hand second-hand"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Clock;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - whenever the DOM is being queried (e.g. calls to `document.querySelector()`, etc.), that might likely be a sign that the Virtual DOM is not being utilized properly.

#### Use the React component state for storing values for degree values

The *styles* can be added inline such that the *degree* values of the transform-rotate styles reference values in the state:

```
<div className="hand hour-hand" style={{transform: `rotate(${this.state.hourDegrees}deg)`}}></div>
<div className="hand min-hand" style={{transform: `rotate(${this.state.minuteDegrees}deg)`}}></div>
<div className="hand second-hand" style={{transform: `rotate(${this.state.secondDegrees}deg)`}}></div>
```

To set those values in the state, update `setDate()` to call `setState()` with those values:

```
setDate() {
    const now = new Date();
    const second = now.getSeconds();
    const minute = now.getMinutes();
    const hour = now.getHours();
    this.setState({
        secondDegrees:  (second/60) * 360 + 90,
        minutesDegrees: (minute/60) * 360 + 90,
        hourDegrees: (hour/12) * 360 + 90
    });
}
```

And in order for the closure to reference `this` of the component properly in the interval callback, it can be bound using [Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)- use that when calling `setInterval()`:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        timer: setInterval(this.setDate.bind(this), 1000)
    }
}
```

The *style* attributes could also be bound to plain-old Javascript objects- this would be useful in case there were multiple in-line styles to attach. For example:

```
render() {
    const hourStyle = {
        transform: `rotate(${this.state.hourDegrees}deg)`
    };
    return (
        <div className="col-md-6">a
            <div className="clock">
                <div className="clock-face">
                    <div className="hand hour-hand" style={hourStyle}></div>
```

Click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/aelliott/8q1rhqbp/21/) for a demonstration in JSFiddle, or expand the snippet below.

```js
var logged = false;
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      timer: setInterval(this.setDate.bind(this), 1000),
      secondDegrees: 0,
      minuteDegress: 0,
      hourDegrees: 0
    }
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.state.timer);
  }
  setDate() {

    const now = new Date();
    const second = now.getSeconds();
    const minute = now.getMinutes();
    const hour = now.getHours();

    const secondDegrees = (second / 60) * 360 + 90;
    const minutesDegrees = (minute / 60) * 360 + 90;
    const hourDegrees = (hour / 12) * 360 + 90;;
    this.setState({
      secondDegrees: (second / 60) * 360 + 90,
      minutesDegrees: (minute / 60) * 360 + 90,
      hourDegrees: (hour / 12) * 360 + 90
    });
  }
  render() {
    const secondStyle = {
      transform: `rotate(${this.state.secondDegrees}deg)`
    };
    const minuteStyle = {
      transform: `rotate(${this.state.minuteDegrees}deg)`
    };
    const hourStyle = {
      transform: `rotate(${this.state.hourDegrees}deg)`
    };
    return ( <
      div className = "col-md-6" >
      <
      div className = "clock" >
      <
      div className = "clock-face" >
      <
      div className = "hand hour-hand"
      style = {
        hourStyle
      } > < /div> <
      div className = "hand min-hand"
      style = {
        minuteStyle
      } > < /div> <
      div className = "hand second-hand"
      style = {
        secondStyle
      } > < /div> <
      /div> <
      /div> <
      /div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  Clock / > ,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
/*Matt Litzinger - http://codepen.io/mlitzinger/pen/ruEyz*/

.clock {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(#3b3b3b, #000);
  background: radial-gradient(#3b3b3b, #000);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 30px #777, 0px 2px 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 20px 40px #bbb;
  border: 6px solid #222;
  border-radius: 106px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.hand {
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}
.hour-hand {
  width: 4px;
  height: 55px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #000;
  top: 45px;
  left: 98px;
}

.min-hand {
  width: 4px;
  height: 80px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000;
  top: 20px;
  left: 98px;
}

.second-hand {
  width: 2px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #bbb;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #000;
  top: 20px;
  left: 99px;
}

.pin {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #111;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.hour-hand,
.minute-hand,
.second-hand {
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: BTW, the minute hand doesn't show because the fiddle uses a classname of `min-hand` instead of `minute-hand` ... I was going crazy trying to figure it out :)